# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is not working when using UIPageViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

My app UI hierarchy look like shown in the picture below.

When I try to push UIViewController for 1st tab it doesn't hide tabbar even hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true.
It works well for 2, 3, 4 tab, when hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true.
How can I solve it?
I have tried, but it only works like described above:

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    set {
        super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = newValue
    }
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

[image]